# Implementing a functional interface to work with InputStreams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

#### The Scenario

I'm trying to dev an `@FuntionalInterface` to work with `InputStream`s.

The main Interfaces is:

- Interface `StreamTransformer<T>`  - transform an `InputStream` into something else.
- Interface `IntermediateStreamTransform` - transform an `InputStream` to another `InputStream` (modified) that will be consumed in another transformer. You can chain transformers to compose an aggregate transformer.
- Interface `StreamTransformResult<T>` - holds the result of the transformation(s).

---

#### The Code

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface StreamTransformResult<T> {
   T getResult() throws IOException;
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface StreamTransformer<T> {
   StreamTransformResult<T> transform( InputStream inputStream ) throws IOException;    
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntermediateStreamTransform {
    InputStream intermediateTransform( InputStream inputStream ) throws IOException;
    
    default IntermediateStreamTransform chain(IntermediateStreamTransform nextTransformer)
        throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(nextTransformer);
        
        return new IntermediateStreamTransform() {
            @Override
            public InputStream intermediateTransform(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                InputStream intermediateStream = this.intermediateTransform(is);
                return nextTransformer.intermediateTransform(intermediateStream);
            }
        };
    }
    
    default <T> StreamTransformResult<T> finalize(InputStream is, StreamTransformer<T> streamTransformer)
        throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(streamTransformer);
        
        return new StreamTransformResult<T>() {
            @Override
            public T getResult() {
                InputStream intermediateStream = this.intermediateTransform(is); //is cannot be resolved
                StreamTransformResult<T> streamTransformResult = streamTransformer.transform( intermediateStream );
                return streamTransformResult.getResult();
            }
        };
    }
    
}
```

---

#### The problem

I'm struggling to develop the `default` `finalize` method in the interface `IntermediateStreamTransform`.

I can't find a way to call the non default method `intermediateTransform(InputStream is)` and pass the `InputStream`.

The algorithm for the method is - on `IntermediateStreamTransform.finalize(StreamTransformer<T> streamTransformer)`:

1. Call the method `intermediateTransform(InputStream is)` : This will perform the intermediate transformations and return an intermediate `InputStream`.
2. Call the method `transform(InputStream)` on the `StreamTransformed` passed as argument : this will perform the final transformation and return the `StreamTransformResult` instance.
3. Return the `StreamTransformResult` instance.

So how can i implement the method?

The GitHub [repo is here](https://github.com/MatheusArleson/StreamTransformersApi).

Comment: Could you please edit your title to be more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto your comment make me think of passing the InputStream as argument. And it make sense because you have two options: 1- chain the intermediate instance with other intermediate instance OR 2- finalize the chain. That's exactly what i need.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto already did that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto wondering all can i modify the question to let you adjust your answer... i really need to sleep.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasFilotto. Waiting for your updated response to mark as answered.

Comment: What’s the purpose of this `StreamTransformResult` interface? Why don’t you return the result `T` directly?

Comment: Updated readme.md with project information. check on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning in your anonymous inner classes of type `IntermediateStreamTransform` and `StreamTransformResult`, `this` will refer to the inner class not to the outer class, you are supposed to prefix it with "`IntermediateStreamTransform.`" in order to refer to the method `intermediateTransform` of the interface `IntermediateStreamTransform` so instead of `this.intermediateTransform(is)` it should be `IntermediateStreamTransform.this.intermediateTransform(is)`. Indeed, otherwise in your anonymous inner class of type `IntermediateStreamTransform` you will get a `StackOverFlowError` when calling `intermediateTransform` as it will call itself indefinitely.

Another way could be to simply use a lambda expression as they are `FuntionalInterface` interfaces and `this` in the body of a lambda expression refers to the outer class which is probably less error prone and verbose.

So your code of your `default` methods could be:

```
default IntermediateStreamTransform chain(IntermediateStreamTransform nextTransformer)
    throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(nextTransformer);

    return is -> {
        InputStream intermediateStream = this.intermediateTransform(is);
        return nextTransformer.intermediateTransform(intermediateStream);
    };
}

default <T> StreamTransformResult<T> finalize(InputStream is, 
    StreamTransformer<T> streamTransformer) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(streamTransformer);

    return () -> {
        InputStream intermediateStream = this.intermediateTransform(is);
        StreamTransformResult<T> streamTransformResult = streamTransformer.transform(
            intermediateStream
        );
        return streamTransformResult.getResult();
    };
}
```

Comment: i noticed later the stackOverflow in the method. I'm currently working on the changes you advised. Thanks. Edit comming...